# In Firefox, how a website can be as default page of 'side view' addon when it's launched?

Tags: firefox-extensions

[Side view](https://github.com/mozilla/side-view/) addon is opened with a Welcome page by default in **Firefox**. Is it possible to change this behaviour, replacing default page with a website page?

Comment: Have you asked the plugin author or checked the documentation?

Comment: Yes, I sent an email to the author and didn't get any reply. it's not been under development for a while

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, by editing the initial HTML of the Side View addon and
re-creating the release.

This is to be found in the file `C:\...\side-view-master\addon\sidebar.html`,
which looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sidebar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sidebar.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page" id="landing-panel">
      <div class="graphic">
        <div class="graphic__overlay">
          <div class="graphic__clouds"></div>
          <div class=graphic__browser></div>
        </div>
        <div class="graphic__shadow"></div>
      </div>
      <h1 class="title">Welcome to Side View</h1>

      <p>
        <a href="https://youtu.be/no6D_B4wgo8" id="watch-tutorial">Watch a tutorial</a>
      </p>
    </div>

    <script src="build/buildSettings.js"></script>
    <script src="sidebar.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To include another website, use for example code similar to this
(untested) template code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sidebar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page" id="landing-panel">
         <iframe src="https://www.example.com" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100vh;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have not tried to install 
[npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)
for creating a release of Side View with the above example.

Here are some references to get you started:

- [What is npm?](https://www.w3schools.com/whatis/whatis_npm.asp)
- [Downloading and installing Node.js and npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm)